# Как все товары сделать вариацией одного?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Имею магазин на вордпресс+вукомерс.
Необходимо сделать так.
Имею например категорию ТОВАРОВ КРАСИТЕЛИ, там у меня находятся много-много товаров - РАЗНЫЕ ЦВЕТА , т.е. синий -зелены-серо-буро-малиновый и так далее.
Я хочу - создать новый товар В ЭТОЙ же категории - ПРОСТО КРАСИТЕЛЬ

- И ВСЕ товары из ЭТОЙ категории сделать вариациями ОДНОГО товара - ПРОСТО КРАСИТЕЛЬ(который я только что создал)
  надеюсь понятно обьяснил
  Можно что-то с этим сделать

Comment: Если по-быстрячку: экспорт csv - правка в экселе - импорт.